# HOW to understand this EXPLAIN plan..? It is looking confusing to me

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 130Mill rows in it. When i EXPLAIN the query, it is showing 130Mill in the rowns column.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

rows: 130 Mill

But when it add a where condition with TABLE1.time_dim_id between 1900 and 2000

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE time_dim_id between 1900 and 2000 ;
```

rows: 60Mill

Why am is surprised is because, there are no NULL values for this time_dim_id value and 
min(time_dim_id) is 1900 AND
max(time_dim_id) is 2000.

Why is this not showing 130Mill rows again under rows section in the 2nd EXPLAIN plan...?

Comment: also, probably because you have an index on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ANALYZE TABLE TABLE1
```

and then again you EXPLAIN - this assumes there is an index on TABLE1.time_dim_id

Comment: YES, there is a COMPOSITE PRIMARY key on time_dim_id along with some other attributes. >But in the WHERE clause, I have given such a time  scale so that every row should come in between that range. how the index here will lessen the rows being scanned....?

Comment: As long as MySQL hasn't analyzed the table, it can't say how many rows are in which timespan, so it has to estimate. ANALAYZE TABLE will read the index ranges and so provide a better accuracy.